# huggingface transformers: truncation strategy in encode_plus

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

[`encode_plus`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.__call__) in huggingface's transformers library allows truncation of the input sequence. Two parameters are relevant: `truncation` and `max_length`. I'm passing a paired input sequence to `encode_plus` and need to truncate the input sequence simply in a "cut off" manner, i.e., if the whole sequence consisting of both inputs `text` and `text_pair` is longer than `max_length` it should just be truncated correspondingly from the right.

It seems that neither of the truncation strategies allows to do this, instead `longest_first` removes tokens from the longest sequence (which could be either text or text_pair, but not just simply from the right or end of the sequence, e.g., if text is longer that text_pair, it seems this would remove tokens from text first), `only_first` and `only_second` remove tokens from only the first or second (hence, also not simply from the end), and `do_not_truncate` does not truncate at all. Or did I misunderstood this and actually `longest_first` might be what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No `longest_first` is not the same as `cut from the right`. When you set the truncation strategy to `longest_first`, the tokenizer will compare the length of both `text` and `text_pair` everytime a token needs to be removed and remove a token from the longest. The could for example mean that it will cut at first 3 tokens from `text_pair` and will cut the rest of the tokens which need be cut alternately from `text` and `text_pair`. An example:

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizerFast

tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

seq1 = 'This is a long uninteresting text'
seq2 = 'What could be a second sequence to the uninteresting text'

print(len(tokenizer.tokenize(seq1)))
print(len(tokenizer.tokenize(seq2)))

print(tokenizer(seq1, seq2))

print(tokenizer(seq1, seq2, truncation= True, max_length = 15))
print(tokenizer.decode(tokenizer(seq1, seq2, truncation= True, max_length = 15)['input_ids']))
```

Output:

```
9
13
{'input_ids': [101, 2023, 2003, 1037, 2146, 4895, 18447, 18702, 3436, 3793, 102, 2054, 2071, 2022, 1037, 2117, 5537, 2000, 1996, 4895, 18447, 18702, 3436, 3793, 102], 'token_type_ids': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'attention_mask': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
{'input_ids': [101, 2023, 2003, 1037, 2146, 4895, 18447, 102, 2054, 2071, 2022, 1037, 2117, 5537, 102], 'token_type_ids': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'attention_mask': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
[CLS] this is a long unint [SEP] what could be a second sequence [SEP]
```

As far as I can tell from your question you are actually looking for `only_second` because it cuts from the right (which is `text_pair`):

```py
print(tokenizer(seq1, seq2, truncation= 'only_second', max_length = 15))
```

Output:

```
{'input_ids': [101, 2023, 2003, 1037, 2146, 4895, 18447, 18702, 3436, 3793, 102, 2054, 2071, 2022, 102], 'token_type_ids': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'attention_mask': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
```

It throw an exception when you try your `text` input is longer as the specified max_length. That is correct in my opinion because in this case it is not any longer a sequnece pair input.

Just in case `only_second` doesn't meet your requirements, you can simply create your own truncation strategy. As an example `only_second` by hand:

```
tok_seq1 = tokenizer.tokenize(seq1)
tok_seq2 = tokenizer.tokenize(seq2)

maxLengthSeq2 =  myMax_len - len(tok_seq1) - 3 #number of special tokens for bert sequence pair
if len(tok_seq2) >  maxLengthSeq2:
    tok_seq2 = tok_seq2[:maxLengthSeq2]

input_ids = [tokenizer.cls_token_id] 
input_ids += tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tok_seq1)
input_ids += [tokenizer.sep_token_id]

token_type_ids = [0]*len(input_ids)

input_ids += tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tok_seq2)
input_ids += [tokenizer.sep_token_id]
token_type_ids += [1]*(len(tok_seq2)+1) 


attention_mask = [1]*len(input_ids)
print(input_ids)
print(token_type_ids)
print(attention_mask)
```

Output:

```
[101, 2023, 2003, 1037, 2146, 4895, 18447, 18702, 3436, 3793, 102, 2054, 2071, 2022, 102]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```